# Node.js spawning parent process and capturing subprocess output

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, cmd, child-process

```
const options = {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  shell: true,
  stdio: 'inherit',
}

const firstCommand = 'pktmon stop'
const secondCommand = 'pktmon filter remove'
const thirdCommand = 'pktmon filter add --ethertype 0x88cc'
const foruthCommand = 'pktmon start --etw --pkt-size 0 --log-mode real-time --comp nics'

const child = require('child_process').spawn(`${firstCommand} && ${secondCommand} && 
${thirdCommand} && ${foruthCommand}`,[], options)

//none of child outputs are triggered by subprocess output
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('stdout', data.toString())
})
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr',data.toString())
})
child.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log('message',data)
})
```

Subprocess output is showed on the terminal but how can i actually capture them and save output to a variable?

the reason im using stdio: 'inherit' is because - when i'm not using it the terminal is freezing when last command being executed..

Comment: Can't you store the output in a global variable? `let output = ''; child.stdout.on('data', function(data) { output += data.toString(); });`

Comment: @GrafiCode hi, I tried that also. the child.stdout.on('data') is not being triggered when subprocess is outputting his events...

Comment: You said `Subprocess output is showed on the terminal`, where does it come from, `stdout`, `stderr` or `message`?

Comment: @GrafiCode this is exactly what im not understanding too, I readed that inherit means the stdios (stdin, stdout, stderr) for the parent process will be handed off to the child process. but still, when using stdio: 'inherit' and setting all these callback functions (stdout,stderr,message) - they wont be triggered. I know that because im not getting the console.log output i configured ('stdout:', data), ('stderr',data) etc..

Comment: also, as per documentation, `spawn` does not accept parameters passed directly to the command name, I mean, the command `pktmon stop` should be spawned with `spawn('pktmon', ['stop'], options)`. Alternative is `exec()` which allows you to write `exec('pktmon stop', (err, stdout, stderr) => {`

Comment: @GrafiCode its possible to execute multiple commands with spawn if you are adding the shell: true parameter to the spawn child

Comment: This must be related to the `inherit` option.  When you say `terminal is freezing when last command being executed`, I see last command is `pktmon start`, does it keep running until you hit `ctrl+c`? I think your child process basically never exits.

Comment: @GrafiCode Last command is foruthCommand variable (pktmon start --etw --pkt-size 0 --log-mode real-time --comp nics)
This is very strange but for example if i get the output from this last command and click CTRL+C i will see that output. The child process wont exist by itself, I want to be able to get the output from sub process into a variable so i can make some data manipulations and then i can kill the process.